# What's a good setup for running Java and PHP applications with SSL on the same server?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, tomcat, java

I have one Java- and one PHP-application which I both want to run on the same machine (using Tomcat).

As far as I can see, I have two options:

- **Option 1:** Do the classic apache-tomcat setup with mod_jk and let apache handle the php requests and forward all requests to the Java application to tomcat.
- **Option 2:** Use only tomcat by installing php on it. So, no extra apache server for handling php.

I don't have much experience with this, so I wondered which option would be the wise one, since I cannot foresee which problems might occur.

I, personally, prefer option 2 because I'd then have to manage just one server instead of two.
However, I have a bad feeling about this since most people out there seem to prefer option 1.

**Which option should I pick?**

**Important:** I need **SSL support available for both** (php and java) applications. As far as I know, creating the CSR file for buying a SSL certificate differs between apache and tomcat (openssl vs. keytool). Since I don't want to purchase two certificates, this has to be kept in mind.

Comment: why not nginx proxy(terminate ssl here) to apache and tomcat? this allows you to scale, when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me I would do option 1. The Apache->Tomcat scenario is well documented and well tested. It is also recommended for sites with any amount of static content. PHP under Tomcat is a less commonly implemented. I suspect that it isn't as mature or as well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 (a somewhat esoteric option) is to run [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus) which provides a PHP implementation in Java. Depends upon your PHP application I guess whether this is viable.

Cheers

Comment: The php application will be Wordpress

Comment: Looks like it's been done. Not sure what the current situation is though... YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is fairly simple and flexible, specially in Linux. In addition you can also connect Apache to Tomcat via mod_proxy (as an alternative to mod_jk). I've been using this setup (with ssl, and several virtual sites) for a while, works nice.

Comment: Do you use only one SSL certificate? If yes, did you create it using openssl or keytool? And did you install it on apache or tomcat?

Comment: I have two certificates (and two IP), installed in Apache, created with openssl, signed by Thawte/Godaddy

Answer (score 0):

I think option 1 is more efficient overall, especially for the PHP side?

I vote for 1.  Also there must be a way to use one certificate.

Comment: Could it be enough to install the certificate on the apache server and tell it to secure all data, which would be tunneled to tomcat, through ssl?

Comment: That sounds right.  For two servers it should be ok, but gets more riskier if using same cert for more servers.  Also maybe seen already:
http://www.verisign.com/ssl/ssl-information-center/ssl-basics/index.html#a16